# .Net Parse JSON from Google

Tags: c#, json, parsing

So I am using  one of the google Id API; https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#manage_registration_tokens_for_push_subscriptions
I have previously been fortunate to have API that had WDSL or similar and been easy to parse into a class. 
But the JSON I got back I can not parse easily.

```
 {
"connectDate":"2018-02-12",
"application":"com.chrome.windows",
"subtype":"wp:https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"authorizedEntity":"xxxxxx",
"rel":{
    "topics":{
        "movies":{
            "addDate":"2018-01-26"
            },
        "anotherTopic":{    
            "addDate":"2018-02-12"
            }
        }
},
"connectionType":"WIFI",
"platform":"WEBPUSH"
}
```

Movies and anotherTopics are the topics I created so I can't add them to my class . Or can I?

There are of course ways to do it treating the json as string and using regex or going through the node as a dynamic object (dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);) but ideally I think it should be a dictionary (I think at least) but can not see how.

And as this is Google I assume there is more standard way to handle this kind of JSON.

I have tried creating a dictionary which I couldn't get working.
Stepping through the nodes I can get the data but end up with code like

```
DateTime.Parse(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer)(obj.First)).First).Value).Value.ToString())
```

I have tried to look for similar JSON parsing exampels but I can not find any.

I did not share my attempt to extract the data in my first edit as I don't think that is the way to do it; it is a hack.

I created a class for it

```
       public class SubscriptionDetails
{
    public DateTime connectDate { get; set; }
    public string application { get; set; }
    public string subtype { get; set; }
    public string authorizedEntity { get; set; }
    public string connectionType { get; set; }
    public string platform { get; set; }
    public topics rel { get; set; }
 }
```

But I am stuck when it comes to defining the subclass topics.

So I tried

```
public class topics  : Dictionary<string, object>
```

which results in one dictionary entry with key topics?
the other option requires a dictionary name

```
public class topics
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> DUMMY { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What class are you talking about?

Comment: Forgot to say I am working in C#. It is parsing the 'topics' node that I am struggling with.

Comment: `topics` will be a `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>`

Comment: I am sorry but I don't really see how can use that. If I add a dictionsry to a class topics it needs a name:

    public class topics  
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> DUMMY { get; set; }
    }

The other option I can think of

   public class topics  : Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>

will not parse (get exception).

Comment: You have a root-level property `rel` - that needs to be a class with 1 property `topics` of the dictionary type I posted above

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to the suggestion from Jamiec I got on the right track.
Of course already the node rel is a dictionary with one item called topics.

So need a few classes to parse the entire thing:

```
    public class SubscriptionDetails
{
    public DateTime connectDate { get; set; }
    public string application { get; set; }
    public string subtype { get; set; }
    public string authorizedEntity { get; set; }
    public string connectionType { get; set; }
    public string platform { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, topicItems>   rel { get; set; }
}

public class topicItems : Dictionary<string, topicData> { }
public class topicData
{
    public DateTime addDate { get; set; }
}
```

But if they add another node to rel in addition to 'topics' this most likely will crash.
Just doesn't seem to be a very good way to structure the data and the deserialised class isn't very user friendly either..

Anyway it works (for now)